# Don't we need a quantity that would be a higher generalization of vector?

Tags: vectors, tensors

(Please note here by just tensors I mean higher order tensors. I know vector is a tensor of rank 1 though).

Consider the following vector:

$\vec v=v^i \vec e_i$

**Clearly $v^i$ is not a vector.** *It is a matrix or array of vector components* (more specifically contravariant vector components). **It is $\vec v$ that is the vector.** $\vec e_i$ is unit vector. So we can see here $\vec v$ & $\vec e_i$ are vectors. Why? because they have both magnitude & direction. You can see the 'vector sign' on v & $e_i$ (unlike $v^i$). 
$v^i$ is just an array of magnitudes(or scalars).

Lets move on to tensors.

$T= T_{ij}^{k} δ_{k}^{ij}$

$δ_{k}^{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta.

I thought tensors were generalizations of scalar or vector in a complete sense i.e. it applies to both magnitude & direction.
When I read this- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_stress_tensor , the Cauchy stress tensor (the typical example of a tensor) is an array of only magnitudes; no directions. So doesn't a tensor then have to contain components with direction as well? -I thought.  This link too suggests that tensors have components that doesn't have direction- [What is the magnitude of a tensor?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2804037/what-is-the-magnitude-of-a-tensor).

If tensors don't have direction for their components (so basically array of tensor components=tensor unlike for vectors ...& *tensor is a generalization of array of vector components; not of vector*), **wouldn't we need a quantity that would be the generalization of vector *per se*?** (Maybe one can say if vector has a magnitude & a direction, the next immediate higher generalization of vector has magnitude, 1-direction & 2-direction...where 2-direction is the next immediate higher generalization of 1- direction & 1-direction=conventional direction. One may call the new quantity as 2-vector & the conventional vector as 1-vector.And similarly one can do for 3-vector or even n-vector).

Comment: What is $\delta_k^{ij}$?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin- It is Kronecker delta.

Comment: Do you actually know what the Kronecker delta is? Give me a definition of your symbol, please.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin- $If \quad i= 1,2,3 ;j= 1,2,3 ;k= 1,2,3 ;\quad then $
$\quad δ_{k}^{ij} =1 \quad if \quad (k,i,j) \quad are \quad even \quad permutation \quad of \quad (1,2,3);\quad -1 \quad if \quad (k,i,j) \quad are \quad odd \quad permutation \quad of \quad (1,2,3);\quad 0 \quad if \quad otherwise.  $ $\quad$
Is the above correct?
Also is 
$δ_{k}^{ij} =e^{i}\otimes e^{j}\otimes \vec e_{k}$ ? $\quad$ where $e^i$ & $e^j$ are unit basis co-vectors & $\vec e_k$ is unit basis vector.
I see here there is direction for $\vec e_k$.

Comment: No, given a basis $e_i$ and dual basis $e^{i*}$ you can write down the expression $\sum \delta_k^{ij} e_i\otimes e_j\otimes e^{k*}$. To say that $\delta_k^{ij}$ "is" (i.e., are the components of) a tensor is to say that this expression stays the same when we change basis. But it does not. This is not a tensor.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin- Are you saying $δ_{k}^{ij}$ is not a tensor here *given my definition of it above*? i.e. if the definition was different, it would have been a tensor? because I saw this- https://physicspages.com/pdf/d%27Inverno/d%27Inverno%20Problems%2005.08.pdf  & in the Kronecker delta & levi-civita symbol section of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.01660.pdf.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin- If $δ_{k}^{i}= 1\quad for \quad k=i;\quad  0 \quad for \quad k\neq i $ then would $δ_{k}^{i}$ in $T=T_{i}^{k}δ_{k}^{i}$ be a tensor? Would then $δ_{k}^{i}=e^{i}\otimes \vec e_{k}$ correct? Another thing that confuses me a lot is the difference between T & $T_{i}^{k}$.Which of T & $T_{i}^{k}$ is a tensor?